# Can "a" be used as "all / any / every / each"?

Tags: indefinite-article

It seems to me we can use "*a*" not only as "*one of many*" but also as "*all / any / every / each*".
Is it so?

---

To check it, I came up with the following sentence:
*If a headache is accompanied by fever, **a** man should see a doctor*.

I think we can't say "man" here without any article.
"***The** man*" would mean a specific man.
But if we want to talk about a man in general, we must use "*a*".
So "***a** man*" here doesn't mean "*one of men*" but means "*all men*" or "*any man*" or "*every / each man*". Am I right?

---

For the same reason, I wrote above: "*if we want to talk about **a** man in general*".
That is, "*a man*" here doesn't mean "*one of men*" but "*all men (people) in general*". Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

I would see it in substitution of pronoun one:

> If a headache is accompanied by fever, one should see a doctor

Anyway you are right, in the example the single is used to talk of the multitude in general circumstances.

Comment: Yes, it would be frowned on nowadays to use 'a man' to mean 'people in general' - but the grammar is correct.

Comment: Or less formally, "*... **you** should see a doctor.*"